# Windows Update completely messed up audio

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

I'm having really bad times and now Windows decided that I cannot even listen to music without my ears bleeding out of the horrible audio quality. Yesterday I got an update which took quite a long time to install, in fact so long that I feel asleep and started using my laptop today. What happened is that I right away noticed something is off with the audio and once I played a song my ears were obliterated. Basses completely gone, audio sounds like I just bought 2 cent Chinese headphones.

I tried uninstalling the driver and restarting, updating drivers and looked for different solutions, but nothing changed it. The audio is complete trash at this point. I have Realtek audio driver and before the update the audio was perfect. The audio console is untouched yet the audio is terrible. Any suggestions?

Comment: At a minimum you will have to [edit] your question and indicate what updates you installed.  We also would need to know what optional device updates were installed.  When [edit] your question to include this required vital information also indicate what version of Windows you are using

Answer (score -1):

Well I had to sacrifice the new windows version and downgrade. I also discovered that not only my audio drivers were broke in the new version but also my RTX 2060 (which handles my second monitor) was having troubles to work on normal resolutions and indicated only 8mb of vram lol. Anyway my solution is to downgrade.

Comment: Downgrade to what version exactly?  This is hardly a real solution to your problem